# What does it really mean to target a framework, and how do I maximize compatibility?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, compatibility, backwards-compatibility

Greetings all,

This has confused me ever since I first started coding in C#.  My goal is to create an assembly that will run on the most recent .NET framework the user has, whatever that may be.  I don't want to require .NET 4 to be installed, but I want to use it if the user has it, and more importantly, I want it to still work if the user has *only* .NET 4 and nothing below.  I'm beginning to suspect this is not even possible.

I don't really understand what I'm selecting when I change the "Target Framework" in Visual Studio.  Does that mean "will be compatible with this version and up"?  Or "will be compatible with only this version"?  It seems like it's the latter so far; my tests in virtual machines show .NET 4 targeted assemblies failing without .NET 4, and .NET 3.5 targeted assemblies failing without .NET 3.5.  Is there no way to set this so I can achieve maximum compatibility?

UPDATE: To clarify, I have a program that targets .NET 2.  The posters here seem to indicate that it should load with .NET 4.  But in an environment with only .NET 4 and nothing before it, it fails to load.

UPDATE2: Okay, figured it out, but it's far more complex than the posters here seem to think.  I'm opening a different question to discuss the intricacies, but the short version is, you need an app.config with `<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />` in it if you want to run non-.NET 4 assemblies on .NET 4.  They won't load without it.

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to write that you want it to use the latest framework possible? In most scenarios, sticking with writing an application in the earliest framework possible is acceptable, otherwise you're going to fund yourself compiling against specific frameworks and trying to play the mix-and-match game based on installed versions.

Comment: It's not that I really want to use the latest framework possible, it's that I want users who only have .NET 4 installed not to have to download and install the *gargantuan* .NET 3.5 framework.

Comment: There's a explanation and example of SupportedRuntime logic here: [To configure your app to run on the .NET Framework 4 or later versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-configure-an-app-to-support-net-framework-4-or-4-5)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The frameworks are designed to be backwards-compatible; if you have a program written in .NET 2.0, you can run it in the 4.0 runtime, because none of the frameworks ever remove functionality that a prior version had (which is why we still have the non-generic collections like ArrayList, even though they're deprecated in favor of generic collections). However, the reverse is not necessarily true; a 4.0 app is not guaranteed to run in 2.0, because it MAY take advantage of new features of the new runtime that are not available in prior versions. In any case, if you want your app to attempt to run on runtime versions it does not specifically target, you must specify that in the app.config using SupportedRuntime elements.

To answer your specific question, you can do what you want with the following basic procedure:

- Develop your app to target the EARLIEST framework version that you want to support. This will disable access to newer features of newer runtimes (like Linq in 3.5, and dynamic typing in 4.0) ensuring your app will not require any feature that cannot be provided by any of the supported runtimes.
- Specify the frameworks that are acceptable to your application by using the  SupportedRuntime element in your app.config file. This will tell the native code that initializes the runtime in which your app will run that if it can't find the targeted version, any of the others are acceptable. I believe the behavior is to look for the targeted framework first, and if not available it should use the newest supported runtime.

Comment: What if newer versions perform better? I have a library which can work with .NET Framework 2.0 but I thought that it might perform better on newer versions because of the optimizations made in years. Therefore, I targeted much newer version, 4.6.1. What do you think about these kind of situations?

Answer (score 2):

.NET is backward-compatible, this means if you select .NET Framework 2.0 as target framework, it will run on installed version 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 4.0. 
But if you select e.g version 4.0 as target framework, it will only run if you have version 4.0 installed.

Comment: This is what I assumed, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  I have tested my application (which is an extension DLL) in a virtual machine with only .NET 4 installed, and it doesn't load.  `ngen` gives me the following error if I try to use it: `Failed to load the runtime. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131700). Assembly {my assembly} requires version v2.0.50727 of the runtime to run.`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how targeting works: If you target .NET 3.5, it will not run if user does not have .NET 3.5. It will run if user has any higher version.

For maximum compatibility, choose .NET 2.0, it will run even on .NET 3.5, 4.0 and so on.

However, you might loose out on new features of .NET such as LINQ etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398197(VS.100).aspx

[Can I still target .NET Framework 2.0 in VisualStudio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916084/can-i-still-target-net-framework-2-0-in-visualstudio-2010)

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* this is supposed to be whatever version you select and upwards.  So if you target 2.0 framework, it should work if client has 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, or 4.0 frameworks installed.

You are also selecting language features when you pick this, so I know of no way that you would be able to use 4.0 framework features using an application targeting 2.0 framework.  Even dynamically loading assemblies doesn't work, try loading a dll compiled to 4.0 from a 2.0 application, it won't let you.